# What happens when filter is passed in pipe?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to understand why the below subscription is not working:

```
  isLoggedIn1$:Observable<boolean> = of(false) // on subscribing it I get value as false

  isLoggedIn2$:Observable<boolean> = of(false).pipe(filter(value => Boolean(value))) // this one is not giving any value even it looks like subscribe is not getting called for this
```

Is there any documentation for this particular behavior?

As I understand it is being treated equivalent to `EMPTY`. but then why I am not getting type error for second one.

Comment: `why I am not getting type error` - why would you ? it's still an Observable that **can** emit Boolean values, it just happens to not do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filter` operator filters the value based on given predicate. If that condition specified by `filter` is fulfilled, then the value will pass down to subscriber else we don't see anything on screen.

For the line

```js
isLoggedIn2$:Observable<boolean> = of(false).pipe(filter(value => Boolean(value)))
```

The predicate here only allows those value to pass further down the pipe that are true

```js
value => Boolean(value)
```

If you want to print `false` you have to modify filter condition as

```js
value => Boolean(value) === false
```

More on filter operator - https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter